# Converting Tuple<List<Guid>, string> to Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I am trying to converting a `Tuple<List<Guid>, string>` to `Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>`. This is what I have so far:

```
var listOfTuples = GetListOfTuples(); // returns type List<Tuple<List<Guid>, string>>
var transformedDictionary = new Dictionary<Guid, List<string>>();
foreach (var listOfTuple in listOfTuples)
{
    foreach (var key in listOfTuple.Item1)
    {
        if (!transformedDictionary.ContainsKey(key)) 
            transformedDictionary[key] = new List<string> { listOfTuple.Item2 };
        else transformedDictionary[key].Add(listOfTuple.Item2);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this, perhaps using LINQ; `SelectMany`, `Grouping`, or `toDictionary`?

**Update**: I have tried this, but clearly not working:

```
listOfTuples.ToList()
 .SelectMany(x => x.Item1,(y, z) => new { key = y.Item2, value = z })
 .GroupBy(p => p.key)
 .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(m => m.key));
```

Comment: Have you tried any linq solution?

Comment: I have. But I was not able to get it to work.

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: It's pretty easy if you split the logic into steps for the LINQ. First you can turn the original list into a 1 to 1 using a `SelectMany` then from there all you need is the proper `GroupBy` and you should be able to figure out with those hints how to do it.

Comment: This seems like an X, Y Problem,  Why do you have that data structure in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. The problem is with selecting the right key and value

```
var result = listOfTuples.SelectMany(t => t.Item1.Select(g => (g, str: t.Item2)))
                         .GroupBy(item => item.g, item => item.str)
                         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

The mistake is here `(y, z) => new { key = y.Item2, value = z }` - you want the `key` to be the `Guid` and therefore instead of it being `Item2` it should be `z` which is the `Guid`. So you can go with the way I wrote it or just

```
(y, z) => new { key = z, value = y.Item2 }
```

*Also the `.ToList()` at the beginning is not needed. You say that `listOfTuples` already returns a list*

Comment: Thank you, @gilad-green. I will try out your correction to my code first. I will analyze your approach as well, which is new to me. I also noticed that in my LINQ code snippet, the last part needs to be updated to `.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(m => m.value))`

Comment: @Tom - Let me know if it helped :) and it's good you posted what you tried